# Is there a system that automatically designs a set of rules from the examples?

Tags: logic, automated-theorem-proving, z3

Being by no means an expert in the field, I do however know of solvers such as [Z3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_Theorem_Prover) that can generate a correct program, provided you can express your constraints as a set of logical rules, such as [here](http://barghouthi.github.io/articles/17/synthesis-primer.html#test-driven-synthesis).

However, in the example given above, logical rules are designed "by hand" from a set of examples, so the "compilation step" from the examples to the set of rules must be done in the user's head.

Does a system automating this "compilation step" exist (i.e automated rule set deduction from a set of examples), that would allow the user to see and make use of the set of rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an active research topic.

Consider reading

- J.Pitrat's [*Artificial Beings, the conscience of a conscious machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015) book
- This [*Understanding machine learning*](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf) book
- old Lenat's papers on [Eurisko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurisko).
- and recent papers such as [*Learning Structured Embeddings of Knowledge Bases*](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/192344/files/Bordes_AAAI_2011.pdf) and several others in [*Artificial Intelligence Journal*](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/artificial-intelligence)
- about the [MILEPOST GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MILEPOST_GCC) and [Ctuning](http://ctuning.org/) projects
- [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352154618301943) on *Reconciling deep learning with symbolic artificial intelligence: representing objects and relations*

My hope is to get funded so that [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) could (in a few years) be able to deduce some rules and metarules.